# How to insert a array of objects into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, echarts

The data I get from Api comes as an array as follows:

```
var arrayX = [{key: "GET", doc_count: 12},
{key: "POST", doc_count: 381}]
```

I want to show the values of this key 'key' and 'doc_cont' in a graph.
And chart format as follows:

```
" ....
data: [{value: 'Doc_count' information of 'POST' key information will come in this field, name: 'POST'},
       {value: put, name: 'PUT'},
       {value: get, name: 'GET'}]
..."
```

When I want to assign a value to 'doc_count' in 'arrayX', 'undefined' is returned.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= arrayX.length; i++) {
            if (arrayX[i].key == 'POST') {
                var post = arrayX[i].doc_count;
            }
            else if (arrayX[i].key == 'PUT') {
                var put = arrayX[i].doc_count;
            }
            else if (arrayX[i].key == 'GET') {
                var get = arrayX[i].doc_count;
            }
}
```

How can I fix this situation?
I hope my question clear.

Comment: This `i <= arrayX.length` should be `i < arrayX.length`. Indices start from `0`. So when loop is in second iteration, `arrayX[1]` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, the only issue here is your loop condition.

change this:

`for (var i = 0; i <= arrayX.length; i++)`

To this:

`for (var i = 0; i < arrayX.length; i++)`

I've change the `<=` to `<`.

If you use `<=` you get the indexes of 0,1 and 2 and as you don't have index 2 in `arrayX` you get the exception (arrays index start from 0).

You can read more in [Arrays index](http://developeronline.blogspot.com/2008/04/why-array-index-should-start-from-0.html)

Comment: Thank you for helping. This code worked by removing the '=' sign.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to convert an Array of following structure:

```
[{key: "GET", doc_count: 12}, {key: "POST", doc_count: 381}]
```

into:

```
[{name: "GET", value: 12}, {name: "POST", value: 381}]
```

For this purpose, `Array.prototype.map()` may be more descriptive way of going about it. 
From the official [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var arrayX = [{
  key: "GET",
  doc_count: 12
}, {
  key: "POST",
  doc_count: 381
}]

var chartData = arrayX.map((item) => {
  return {
    name: item.key,
    value: item.doc_count
  }
});

console.log(chartData)
console.log(arrayX)
```